# Volume reconstruction from 3D image gradient in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, volume-rendering

For 2D images- Gx and Gy gives the information on vertical and horizontal edge infromation respectively. Angle of the gradient direction vector can be calculated from inverse of tan(Gy/Gx) and edge direction will be perpendicular to the gradient direction vector.

I have 3D Z-stacked image datset so each pixel will be represented by (x,y,z) co-ordinate and with respective intensity value as well. I have used [3D image gradient link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26851430/calculating-the-gradient-of-a-3d-matrix) for initial reference.

(1) What if I want to derive whole volume/wireframe model just with the information of 3D image gradient magnitude and direction?

(2) Do I need X, Y and Z-stacked image data seperately in order to generate whole volume/wireframe model out of it?

In matlab, I can also develop whole volume just with 2D z-stacked masks using [isosurface command](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/techniques-for-visualizing-scalar-volume-data.html#f5-14693). Here I am exploring other possibilities to generate wireframe volume/3D model.

Thanking you in anticipation.